# Missed class-- Super confused on how to do this -- Mean & Variance of IID -- uniform distribution

Tags: probability

I unfortunately missed class and I've been desperately looking everywhere to find example questions similar to this and I can't find anything. Can somebody please either post something step-by-step on how this question is done or link e to a question similar to it? Thank you so much!

*I tried to figure out the expected value (is it 1/n! ?) but I have no idea.

[image: qna]

Comment: I don't think there is any connection to factorials. Are you familiar with the definition of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$?

Comment: I know it means that the PDF of each is 1.

Comment: More precisely, the pdf $f(x)=1$ if $0<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. The expected value is then just $\int xf(x)\;dx=\int_0^1\;xdx$.

Comment: Thank you! And to calculate the variance am I just supposed to use the formula 1/12(b-a)^2 ?

Comment: Yes, or you can calculate it using $\mathrm{var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I really appreciate it.